# Integration problems

Tags: numerical-integration

for solving the following integral I have used two different methods. The first way answer is zero while the second one answer is very large. What is the best way to solve such integrals?

```
 b = 10^-9;
 Δ = 10^-3;
 h = 10^-1;
 δ =-10^-6;
 Ω = -h Sqrt[Δ^2 +δ^2]; 
 t = 100;
 NIntegrate[E^(-w/b) w (Sin[(w-Ω) t]/(2 (w-Ω)^2)), {w,0,1},
 MinRecursion->20, MaxRecursion-> 300, AccuracyGoal -> 10]
 out=0
 N[Integrate[E^(-w/b) w (Sin[(w-Ω) t]/(2 (w-Ω)^2)), {w, 0, 1}]]
 out=-1.630819617920249*10^43427 - 1.811152402730411*10^43420 i
```

Comment: What is `t` supposed to be?

Comment: Ω is a negative number. Why then do you include it as a singularity within the integration interval 0 and 1?

Comment: Your first expression does not give zero, it gives a similarly huge number. You are computing things on the order Exp[1/b] which is like 10^434294481. You are running into issues with the accuracy of the Exp function for such large numbers.  (*are you sure your formulation is correct?*)

Answer (score 1):

When you have some confusion about your function, the best starting point is to plot is first. You have an  `E^(-w/b)` with a `b=10^-9`, so definitely the function is dead (=0) for `w>10^-7`.

```
Plot[E^(-w/b) w (Sin[(w - Ω) t]/(2 (w - Ω)^2)), {w, 0, 10^-7}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
NIntegrate[E^(-w/b) w (Sin[(w -Ω) t]/(2 (w - Ω)^2)), {w, 0, 10^-7}]
```

> 4.99981*10^-13

You will get the same result with `10^-6` or `10^-5`. Therefore my suggestion for this kind of integration would be to find the proper limit first. You can use a limit `{0,w,1}`, but the actual contribution is coming from `w<10^-7` and to get the same result with that limit you have to increase the precession with the same scale which, I don't think would be very efficient.